# Error: Cannot got to specified record. Access 2007 and SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2007

I have inherited an Access 2007 database that has been split so the
tables are on a SQL 2005 server.

The database consists of 3 tables and 3 forms.  The main form that is
used reads and writes to all 3 tables.  Data can be edited and deleted
OK but trying to add a new record throws an error saying, "You can't
go to the specified record"

The code for the new record button is an embedded macro with the
follow parameters:

```
  OnError Next,
  GoToRecord ,,New,
  [MacroError]<>0 MsgBox =[MacroError].[Description],Yes,None,
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether all *required* fields of the record are present when you do the insert or if the constraints are met (such as having a duplicate value for a field that does not allow duplicates).